# How to post the grid column name while updating data using Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am having a hard time to get the Kendo Grid column title name when I click on update button.
What I'm trying to do is, by getting column title name I need to get the id of that particular column from database and after that I will do update query using Id of that column,month_id and login user I'd.

I didn't fetch I'd for all column while reading data.

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oyWB.png)

I have use parameterMap to return model data but how to return grid column title names.

OR
Is there any other way to do this?
Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I would first check out Telerik's [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline) for inline-editing. I don't know if you're using Javascript or MVC, but you can find examples for both there.

Comment: @Supersnake Thanks for the reply. I am using Javascript.But the requirement I have is to post the grid column name to server (I'm using PHP) to use that name to fetch the ID from DB.